# How do I replace the argument in countif in a static formula with a word or result of a formula on another sheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to replace this static formula

```
=COUNTIFS(GPS!$J:$J,"Create Order List*",GPS!$D:$D,ScoreCard!$B16)
```

with something like this

```
=COUNTIFS(GPS!$J:$J,=CELL("contents",Task!F9),GPS!$D:$D,ScoreCard!$B16)
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(GPS!$J:$J,=Task!F9,GPS!$D:$D,ScoreCard!$B16)
```

I have also tried =Text etc.
where  `Task!F9` is a cell where "Create Order List*" is typed in on the TASK sheet.
the 123 Derivative @CELL("contents") had no such problem doing this successfully in 123. I need the dynamic ability to have the formula manipulated via a reference to the task page. I have tried it without the = sign in front of the cell and with a + instead . Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you want. What's wrong with `=COUNTIFS(GPS!$J:$J,Task!F9,GPS!$D:$D,ScoreCard!$B16)`?

Comment: @findwindow you may want to block Task!$F$9.

Comment: It simply won't work... It doesn't provide an error however it also won't return the count.  It will not offer the result that the static words "Create Order List" will.   It has to be something with the evaluation precedence or type... No clue I just know I did this a lot in 123 with @CELL("contents") and it allways worked but EXCELL evaluates it differently evidently.  Try it yourself.  The problem is the search parameter needs to be dynamic in the formula based on a text label in another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(GPS!$J:$J,Task!F$9&"*",GPS!$D:$D,Scorecard!$B16)
```

Assumes `Task!F$9` contains `Create Order List`.